# Python compare integer number with hexadecimal and binary numbers

Tags: python, hex

How can I compare a `int` number with hexadecimal and binary number?

Is there any other methods available other than I found below:

```
if b'\xFF'[0] == 255:
    print("yes")

if bin(b'\xFF') == bin(255)
    print("yes")
```

Above is doing some sort of calls and conversions. I would be surprised that if it is not possible to define a number with any input format(binary, hex, decimal) and that is still the same number for the compiler.

Almost any compiler, I know so far,  can represent a number with different notations, but no way in Python, like this one:

```
if 255 == 0xFF
    print("yes")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is valid expression. You just missed ":" at the end of if statement

```
if 255 == 0xFF:
 print("yes")
```

Answer (score 5):

## **`int` - `hex` (Integer - Hexadecimal) comparison**:

You may use [**`hex()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) to **convert `int` value to `hex`** as:

```
>>> hex(255)
'0xff'
```

Example for comparing the `hex` value with `int` can be done as:

```
>>> hex(255) == '0xff'
True
```

OR, use [**`int()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) with *base 16* to **convert `hex` to `int`**:

```
>>> int('0xff', 16)
255
```

Now this `int` can be compared with `hex` as:

```
>>> int('0xff', 16) == 255
True
```

Also, *Hex number without quotes (quotes denotes `str`) is automatically convert to `int` by Python interpreter*. For example:

```
>>> 0xff
255
```

Hence, you may also do direct comparison as:

```
>>> 255 == 0xff  # `0x` at the start denotes hexa-decimal number
True
```

---

## **`int` - `bin` (Integer - Binary) comparison**:

You may use [**`bin()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) to **convert `int` value to binary** as:

```
>>> bin(5)
'0b101'
```

Here's the example comparing `int` with `bin` value:

```
>>> bin(5) == '0b101'
True
```

OR, use [**`int()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) with base 2 to **convert `bin` to `int`**:

```
>>> int('0b101', 2)
5
```

Using this, comparison of binary with `int` can be done as:

```
>>> int('0b101', 2) == 5
True
```

*Python interpreter converts quote-less binary number to int*:

```
>>> 0b101   # `0b` at the start denotes binary number
5
```

Hence, you may compare int with binary as:

```
>>> 5 == 0b101
True
```